# How to write a Protocol buffers message?

Tags: java, protobuf-java

How to add a field of long type in a protobuf message?
For the following case, myId is a field of type long.

```java
public class Dummy implements Serializable {

    @Field("my_id")
    @JsonProperty("my_id")
    private Long myId;
}
```

Comment: ...add it to the protobuf defintion file?

Answer (score 0):

The guide of protobufs for [scalar types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar):

This is an example of protobuf message with a Long that is mapped to int64 in protobuf:

```
message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1;
  int64 page_number = 2;
  int64 result_per_page = 3;
}
```